# Excel VBA - Copy pasting tab causing errors

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am writing a macro to create a new tab in the file, name it, and copy it from an existing template tab.  In doing so, a popupbox appears searching for a file titled "Update values: wbname.xlsm" , which I then have to cancel out of.  I'm not sure why this error might occur (although the tab uses many indirect formulas, for what it's worth), but if there is an explanation of how to prevent this popupbox, or how to build closing it into the code, that'd be very helpful.

Also, I added the second copy paste portion as column widths were not coming through initially, but that also causes a run-time error 1004 saying "all merged cells need to be the same size.  If there is a better way to copy this, I'd appreciate it, but otherwise I guess I'd do "on error resume next."

Here's the code:

```
TabName = InputBox("Please enter your testing date?") 
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = TabName
Sheets("Template").Range("A1:BZ300").Copy Destination:=Sheets(TabName).Range("A1")
Sheets("Template").Range("A1:BZ300").Copy
With Sheets(TabName).Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
Calculate
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Your first step should be to step through the code to figure out which lines are causing these problems.  See Chip Pearson's guide to [Debugging VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).  Then, you could [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].  (Also, check out the [tour] to earn a badge!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that A1:BZ300 is the entire used range of the template worksheet. In that case, just copy the entire template worksheet and resolve the formulas into their values.

You can temporarily suspend during the operation with UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever.

```
Dim tabName As String, oldUL As Long

tabName = InputBox("Please enter your testing date?")

With ThisWorkbook
    oldUL = .UpdateLinks
    .UpdateLinks = xlUpdateLinksNever

    .Worksheets("template").Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
    With .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
        .Name = tabName
        .UsedRange.Cells = .UsedRange.Cells.Value
        .Cells(1).Select
    End With

    .UpdateLinks = oldUL
End With
```